# Pulling exception out of its users

Tags: c#, debugging, exception

What is your best solution for pulling out an exception occurring on a user computer?

For example I send automatically a email when an exception is thrown which body contains the call stack.

Have you experience other quick way to handle user bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this is a corporate app, be sure to **ask** the user if they want to submit anything first.

Then, generally I would recommend submitting it via web service. Better to leverage the end-user's existing proxy settings if any.

Answer (score 1):

[ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is a good tool for logging exceptions in ASP.NET websites - it can log the exception to a local database as well as emailing it.

> "Once ELMAH has been dropped into a
>   running web application and configured
>   appropriately, you get the following
>   facilities without changing a single
>   line of your code:  Logging of nearly
>   all unhandled exceptions.
>
> - A web page to remotely view the    entire log of recoded exceptions.
> - A web page to remotely view the full    details of any one logged
>     exception.
> - In many cases, you can review the    original yellow screen of death that
>     ASP.NET generated for a given
>     exception, even with customErrors
>     mode turned off.
> - An e-mail notification of each error    at the time it occurs.  An
>     RSS feed    of the last 15 errors from
>     the log."

Answer (score 0):

BugzScout with FogBugz worked wonders for me.  An API to your bug database in general is the way to go.

With respect to emailing it, you can simulate some of the features of a bug tracking database but it's not as good as the real thing.  If you keep with the email option, be sure to send them to a generic bugs@companyX.com email instead of a personal so they can be routed to a different person quickly if necessary.